# When finding $y_2$ for the method of variational parameters, do the constants matter?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently solving $t^2y''-2ty'+2y=4t^2$, where $y_{1}=t$. When solving for $y_{2}=uy_{1}$, I get that $u''=1$. Would that mean my $y_{2}=\frac{t^3}{2}+C_{1}t^2+C_{2}t$ or just $y_{2}=\frac{t^3}{2}$. My textbook shows an example where it disregards the constants from integration, but I am not sure if that is only limited to when $u''=u'$ ($y_{2}=te^t$).

Comment: The constants give the solution of  the homogeneous DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t^{2}y''-2ty'+2y=4t^{2}$

One of the bases of the answer is t

y<sub>1</sub>=t

y=u y<sub>1</sub>=ut

$y'=u't+u$ , $y''=u''t+2u'$

$t^{2}(u''t+2u')-2t(u't+u)+2ut=4t^{2}$

$t^{3}u''+2t^{2}u'-2t^{2}u'-2tu+2ut=4t^{2}$

$tu''=4$

let : $u'=z$ , $u''=z'$

$tz'=4$

${\int dz}={\int 4t^{-1}dt}$

$z=4ln(t)+c$ , $z=u'$

$u={\int (4ln(t)+c) dt}$

$u=4tln(t)-4t+ct+$c<sub>1</sub> , $c-4=$c<sub>2</sub> , $y=ut$

y=c<sub>1</sub>t+c<sub>2</sub>$t^{2}$+4$t^{2}$ln(t)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what edit ?! Is my answer wrong??!

Answer (score 1):

$$t^2y''-2ty'+2y=4t^2$$
$$y''-2\left(\dfrac {y'}t-\dfrac y{t^2}\right)=4$$
$$y'-2\dfrac {y}t=4t+C_1$$
$$t^2y'-2t {y}=4t^3+C_1t^2$$
$$\left(\dfrac {y}{t^2}\right)'=\dfrac 4{t}+\dfrac {C_1}{t^2}$$
$$\left(\dfrac {y}{t^2}\right)=4\ln{t}+\dfrac {C}{t}+C_2$$
$$ {y(t)}=4{t^2}\ln{t}+{C}{t}+C_2t^2$$

The log function is missiing in your particular solution. You can consider $4t^2\ln t$ as the particular solution or $y_p=4t^2\ln t +t +t^2$ or any other combination of $4t^2 \ln t$ and $t,t^2$.because the $t$ and $t^2$ terms are absorbed by the homogeneous solution $y_h$.